# Git push stopped working, error code is 92

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am experiencing issues when I am trying to push my changes to gitlab.
This is happening since 2-3 days and I could not find any solution for that.

I used the garbage collector already to clean the local repo.
I changed the bufferSize.
I change the http version to 1.1 and back to 2.

But I still receive this error code:

```
RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)
```

I also tried to remove all files and just push an empty file. but this is not working either. It is always stuck at some point. The repo size is pretty huge, because of the .git folder. Even with an empty file and the .git folder the size is at 400mb at 13%. So I think there is an issue in the .git folder?!

Thanks

Jan

Edit: I also tried to create a new gitlab project and there the push is working. Also with another project which exists as well, but has a lot less of size

Comment: Have you tried contacting gitlab directly for support?

Comment: I was able to fix it now. I asked gitlab and they couldnt help me. So I deinstalled everything and reinstalled it. Now it is working